# time complexity for loop justification

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, notation

Hi could anyone explain why the first one is True and second one is False?

[image]

Comment: "..the *number* is in O(n^2).."? [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) does not cover numbers, therefor it does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First loop , number of times the loop gets executed is k times, 
 Where for  a given  n,  i takes values 1,2,4,......less than n.

```
              2 ^ k <= n
              Or,  k <= log(n).
```

Which implies , k the number of times the first loop gets executed is log(n), that is time complexity here is O(log(n)).

Second loop does not get executed based on p as p is not used in the decision  statement of for loop. p does take different values inside the loop, but doesn't influence the decision statement, number of times the p*p gets executed, its time complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize with an example, suppose the value of `n` is 8 then the possible values of `i` are 1,2,4,8 as soon as 8 comes look will break. You can see loop run for 3 times i.e. log(n) times as the value of `i` keeps on increasing by 2X. Hence, True.

For the second part, its is a normal loop which runs for all values of `i` from 1 to n. And the value of p is increasing be the factor p^2n. So it should be O(p^2n). Thats why it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

O(logn):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i=i*c){// Any O(1) expression}
```

Here, time complexity is O(logn) when the index i is multiplied/divided by a constant value.

In the second case,

```
for(p=2,i=1,i<n;i++){ p=p*p }
```

The incremental increase is constant i.e `i=i+1`, the loop will run n times irrespective of the value of p. Hence the loop alone has a complexity of O(n). Considering naive multiplication p = p*p is an O(n) expression where n is the size of p. Hence the complexity should be **O(n^2)**

Comment: if it is in O(n^2) shouldn't it also be in O(n^n)?

Comment: @Seoi Min, think of it as n for loops. The complexity in the exponential form is added not multiplied. Since we have two O(n) instances, it will be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why some algorithm is `O(log n)` it is enough to check what happens when `n = 2^k` (i.e., we can restrict ourselves to the case where `log n` happens to be an integer `k`).

If we inject this into the expression

```
for(i=1; i<2^k; i=i*2) s+=i;
```

we see that `i` will adopt the values `2, 4, 8, 16,...`, i.e., `2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4,...` until reaching the last one `2^k`. In other words, the body of the loop will be evaluated `k` times. Therefore, if we assume that the body is `O(1)`, we see that the complexity is `k*O(1) = O(k) = O(log n)`.